# Disable loop completion when programming perl

Tags: auto-complete-mode, programming, perl

When I type a loop keyword (`for`, `while`, `do`) in perl program, emacs automatically inserts brackets and parenthesizes to complete the loop structure. I would like to disable this but I'm not sure what is actually doing it. I have CPerl, Flymake, AC, Outl, and Abbrev modes loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like cperl-mode always rewrites its abbreviations, my previous answer is not a long term solution.

A better solution is to run a hook after cperl has been loaded and redefine the `cperl-mode-abbrev-table`. Add it to your emacs configuration file after other commands modifying cperl. I've removed the loop abbreviations from the redefined table, but `if` and `do` expansions are still there.

```
(add-hook 'cperl-mode-hook
        (lambda ()
          (clear-abbrev-table cperl-mode-abbrev-table)
          (define-abbrev-table 'cperl-mode-abbrev-table
            '(
              ("=head1" "=head1" cperl-electric-pod 0)
              ("=head2" "=head2" cperl-electric-pod 0)
              ("=over" "=over" cperl-electric-pod 0)
              ("=pod" "=pod" cperl-electric-pod 0)
              ("continue" "continue" cperl-electric-else 0)
              ("do" "do" cperl-electric-keyword 0)
              ("else" "else" cperl-electric-else 0)
              ("elsif" "elsif" cperl-electric-keyword 0)
              ("head1" "head1" cperl-electric-pod 0)
              ("head2" "head2" cperl-electric-pod 0)
              ("if" "if" cperl-electric-keyword 4)
              ("over" "over" cperl-electric-pod 0)
              ("pod" "pod" cperl-electric-pod 0)))))
```

Comment: Great, but now when I close emacs, it asks "Save abbrevs in ~/.emacs.d/abbrev_defs? (y or n)".

Comment: Add `(setq save-abbrevs 'silently)`.

Answer (score 2):

cperl creates abbreviations for perl keywords into `~/.emacs.d/abbrev_defs` that trigger function `cperl-electric-keyword` that does the expansion.

To remove the offending entries, call `M-x edit-abbrevs`,
remove the lines you want, save, and press `C-c C-c` to activate the changes.

Comment: That works for the current session, but when I run emacs again, the entries are back in the cperl-mode-abbrev-table. Even when I save the .emacs.d/abbrev_defs file.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell for the little bit you've provided but you may want to start with (setq cperl-electric-parens nil) and lookup perl-hairy in the documentation